# Return value of object in NSDictionary with several keys

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

I am getting a string from a NSURLRequest. Then I am deserialising the string to convert it to a NSDictionary as follows:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                   if(responseString && responseString.length) {
                                       NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
                                       NSError *jsonError;
                                       NSData *objectData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                       NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                                                            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                              error:&jsonError];
                                       NSLog(@"STRING DESERIALIZADA=%@",json);
```

I get the following result for the json NSDictionary:

```
{
    meta =     {
        limit = 20;
        next = "<null>";
        offset = 0;
        previous = "<null>";
        "total_count" = 1;
    };
    objects =     (
                {
            color = Plata;
            "current_latitude" = "-12.19061989";
            "current_longitude" = "-77.004078";
            employee =             {
                active = 1;
                dni = 78965412;
                id = 2;
                lastname = volongo;
                mail = "rv@alosda.pe";
                name = Ronaldo;
                phone = 12355688;
                photo = "http://example_url/media/employee/default.png";
                "resource_uri" = "/rest/employee/2/";
            };
            id = 1;
            "license_plate" = 2752727;
            model = Toyota;
            "property_card" = "AAA-XXX";
            "resource_uri" = "/rest/clientaxiradio/1/";
            state = 0;
            year = 2014;
        }
    );
}
```

This time, the result includes 1 object under the "objects" key, but in the future there will be more objects in the result response.

What I need to know is how to retrieve the value of each of the objects keys in this case (with only 1 object) and also when the response includes more than one objects.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your last sentence. Are you asking how to retrieve all of the `objects` from `object`, or how to retrieve more than one `object` (with it's children) from a dictionary?

Comment: @l'L'l, sorry for my english, I mean, for example, how to retrieve the value of current_location from the only object that is now in the NSDictionary, and later, when the dictionary may have more than one object, how to retrieve the values of current_latitude from all the objects.

Comment: you can keep the object in NSArray.. and that NSArray array will be array of dictionaries

Comment: Suppose your complete data is in NSDictionary json 

for Object
you can write

    NSArray * objects=[json objectForKey:@"objects"];

This array will contain all the dictionaries within the object

Further you can parse the json with using objects array now

Comment: @Rajan, done, but now how can I retrieve the values for the different keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *fastest* method might be using `NSEnumerator` to get the values you want. In the example below you'll see how to `enumerate` through all keys, and also individual keys:

```
// NSEnumerator
id key = nil;
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [[json allKeys] objectEnumerator];
while ((key = [enumerator nextObject]))
{
    id object = json[key];
    NSLog(@"%@",object); // output all objects values in NSDictionary json
}

// Fast Enumeration
for (id key in [json allKeys])
{
    id object = json[key];
    NSLog(@"%@",object); // output all objects values in NSDictionary json 
}
```

If you had multiple `object` keys in your `NSDictionary` you could do:

```
NSDictionary *obj = [json objectForKey:@"object"]
for (id key in obj)
{
    id object = json[key];
    NSLog(@"%@",object); 
   // output all objects values in NSDictionary json from "object" key
}
```

If `object` was an `NSArray` within the `NSDictionary`:

```
NSArray *obj = [json objectForKey:@"object"];
    for (id key in obj)
    {
        id object = key;
        NSLog(@"%@",object);
    }
```

If you wanted one individual keys `object`:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"current_latitude"]); // would output -12.19061989
```

See `Fast Enumeration` at Apple Developer Website for more information.

Comment: I have implemented all your proposals, but in all cases, the output for the object for key @"current_latitude" is (null). The NSLog for all object is ok.

Comment: Since the `objects` key is an array or dictionary you'll want to use that for `current_latitude`. So you would do something such as `[objects objectForKey:@"current_latitude"];` Also I would recommend not using `objects` or `object` as a dictionary key - it will only end up confusing you, and it's not good practice to use constants names as vars.

Comment: I see what the problem is with `current_latitude`; it's surrounded by quotes - so either get rid of them or change it to `[json objectForKey:@"\"current_latitude\""];`